# Difference between ASP.NET textboxt and html textbox

Tags: asp.net, html

i have a simple Login web application form project. The requirements is using vb.net or asp.net. and using Mssql as the database. what is the difference between the html textboxt and asp.net:textbox? will there be a problem if i used a html textbox? please help.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET textbox will become a html textbox when it is rendered.

ASP.NET textbox has additional properties and methods and certain events which are related to server side

If you use a html textbox without a `runat="server"`, you'll not be able to access its value in c# or vb.net

Comment: can you explain more the meaning of server side. having the hard time of understanding it from what i have searched. can i create a class for asp.net textboxt for designing it using css?